# Looking for a better way to diff 2 arrays

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got a list of objects that I want to display in a table. I'm using `Firebase`, which allows me to monitor a particular list of data and get notifications whenever the list changes.

I have a `PersonViewController` class that has a `UITableView` and has a `people` property to house the list of objects I want to display:

```
var people: [Person] = []
```

I'm updating this property via the `Firebase` call:

```
personRef.observe(.value, with: { [unowned self] snapshot in
  let personDict = snapshot.value as! [String: [String: Any]]
  self.people = personDict.map { Person(dictionary: $0.1) }
  self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

This updates my `people` array whenever the list changes.

At the moment, I'm updating the tableView by calling `tableView.reloadData()`. I only want to reload the things that changed:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.reloadRows(at: /* the indexes of the changed elements */, with: .automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Is there a convenient method/process within `Firebase` or `Foundation` that returns me a list of the indexes that changed? Or would I need to compute that manually?

Comment: How will you know that _things have changed_?

Comment: the `observe` method always calls the `with` closure whenever the array changes.

Comment: Is there something in the Person class or struct whatever it is that is unique from every other cell datasource?

Comment: @Dravidian yes - There's a `UUID` associated with every `Person` object. I could parse the array and compare the old and new array, but I was hoping there was some built in method that does that diff for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be update a client-side structure or UI on a more granular level, you should subscribe to child events.

From the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events):

```
// Listen for new comments in the Firebase database
commentsRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
  self.comments.append(snapshot)
  self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.comments.count-1, section: self.kSectionComments)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
})
// Listen for deleted comments in the Firebase database
commentsRef.observe(.childRemoved, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
  let index = self.indexOfMessage(snapshot)
  self.comments.remove(at: index)
  self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: self.kSectionComments)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
})
```

This snippet listens for when a child gets added or removed, then updates the local `comments` array and the table view for the change.